# Tomcat 8.5.51 - Issues with secretRequired="false"

Tags: tomcat, connector, ajp, tomcat8.5, protocol-handler

The `secretRequired="false"` option added to `AJP` connector is `server.xml`. However, the connector does not start with `Protocol handler start failed` error. It is behind an Apache Server version 2.4.25.

```
    <Connector port="8009"
               address="127.0.0.1" tomcatAuthentication="false" URIEncoding="UTF-8" enableLookups="false"
               protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8663" connectionTimeout="600000" secretRequired="false" />
```

The error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The AJP Connector is configured with secretRequired="true" but the secret attribute is either null or "". This combination is not valid.
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you happen to have a second AJP connector in server.xml?

Comment: No, there is only one AJP. There is also a HTTP connection.

Comment: In Tomcat 8.5.56 the issue is gone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding the `address` attribute and specifying the loopback address is what worked for me on Tomcat 8.5.54.

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" address="0.0.0.0" secretRequired="false" />
```

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is *not* the loopback address; this should be `127.0.0.1`, or `::1` (which is the default anyway). Explicitly using `0.0.0.0` will give you a security problem when combined with `secretRequired="false"`.

Answer (score 5):

Tomcat 9.0.34 has that secretReqiured set to true by default now to address CVS issue.

See these URLs for details of this issue:
`https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4851251
 https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/ajp.html
 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20377`

Comment: You can see that in the original question the parameter is turned off. Are you saying that it is no longer possible to override the default?

Comment: If we add secret value then the documentation of worker.properties from apache2 states that ajp only accept those worker request which has this secret value, Can you tell me how to configure this secret in worker.properties ? or how to pass this secret in request